# Problem closing a card modal on JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a card that opens when the user select a specific project and click on it. Then the card opens showing all data. The problem that I'm facing is that when I'm closing the card (clicking on the span "x") the card is removed, but it's created again as soon as the other card has been removed. I know that I need to break the loop when the card is removed, but I'm not being able to fix this problem. What am I missing?

Code:

```
async function createCard(i) {
  div.appendChild(exit);     
  div.appendChild(title);
  div.appendChild(innerDiv);                             
  innerDiv.appendChild(createGifWrapper(i));
  innerDiv.appendChild(createDescriptionWrapper(i));
}

function handleCard() {    

for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    // cards is an Array of objects that contain all data from each project
    cards[i].addEventListener('click', listerner = function(e) {                

        if(document.querySelector('.card')) {
            if(document.getElementById(i)) {
                console.log('has card and id')
            }
        } else {
            if(this.id === `card-${i+1}`) {                    
                title.textContent = titles[i].innerText;
                this.appendChild(div);
                div.setAttribute('id', i+1);
                createCard(i);                
                // Exit = Span
                exit.addEventListener('click', function() {
                    console.log(document.getElementById(i+1));
                    let card = document.getElementById(i+1);  
                    return card.remove();
                    // Should break here                                           
                })
            }              
        } 
    })   
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As nobody has answered me. I found a solution by myself and would like to share if anyone step up on this problem one day.

```
import { langData } from '../Languages/langData';
```

export async function portfolio() {
    /**
     * Data for each card project
     */
    let cardData
    let defaultText

```
switch(location.hash) {
    case('#pt-br'):
        cardData = langData['pt-br'].portfolio.cardData
        defaultText = langData['pt-br'].portfolio.defaultTitles
        console.log(defaultText)
        break;
    case('#en'):
        cardData = langData['en'].portfolio.cardData
        defaultText = langData['en'].portfolio.defaultTitles    
        break;
}
await console.log('teste')

/**
 * Creating card
 */
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.project-card')
// Exit button 
const exit = document.createElement('span')
// Card Title
const titles = document.querySelectorAll('.project-title')
let title = document.createElement('h3')
    title.setAttribute('class', 'card-title')
// GIFs    
const gifWrapper = document.createElement('div')
const gifMobile = document.createElement('img')
const gifDesktop = document.createElement('img')
// Description
const descriptionTitle = document.createElement('h4')
const description = document.createElement('h5')
const toolsTitle = document.createElement('h4')
const tools = document.createElement('h5')
const descriptionWrapper = document.createElement('div')
// Inner Div - card-details
const innerDiv = document.createElement('div')
let divCard = document.createElement('div')
    divCard.setAttribute('class', 'card')

async function destroyCard() {
    await exit.remove()
    await gifMobile.remove()
    await gifDesktop.remove()
    await gifWrapper.remove()
    await descriptionTitle.remove()
    await description.remove()
    await toolsTitle.remove()
    await tools.remove()
    await descriptionWrapper.remove()
    await innerDiv.remove()
    await divCard.remove()
}

function createExit() {    
    exit.setAttribute('class', 'card-exit')
    exit.textContent = 'x'        
    exit.addEventListener('click', function() {
        destroyCard()
    })
    return exit
}


function createInnerDiv(i) {
        innerDiv.setAttribute('class', 'card-details')   
        innerDiv.appendChild(createGifWrapper(i))
        innerDiv.appendChild(createDescriptionWrapper(i))

    return innerDiv
}

// GIF - Return gifWrapper div with gifs mobile and desktop inside it
function createGifWrapper(i) {    
    gifDesktop.setAttribute('src', cardData[i].gifDesktop)    
    gifMobile.setAttribute('src', cardData[i].gifMobile)        
    gifWrapper.setAttribute('class', 'gif-wrapper')
    gifWrapper.appendChild(gifDesktop)
    gifWrapper.appendChild(gifMobile)  

    return gifWrapper        
}

// Description - return descriptionWrapper div with the description and tools
function createDescriptionWrapper(i) {
    // Description
    descriptionTitle.textContent = defaultText[0]['DescriptionTitle']    
    description.setAttribute('class', 'description')
    description.textContent = cardData[i].description

    // Toools
    toolsTitle.textContent = defaultText[0]['Tools']
    tools.setAttribute('class', 'description')
    tools.textContent = cardData[i].tools

    // Wrapper
    descriptionWrapper.setAttribute('class', 'card-description')
    descriptionWrapper.appendChild(descriptionTitle)
    descriptionWrapper.appendChild(description)
    descriptionWrapper.appendChild(toolsTitle)
    descriptionWrapper.appendChild(tools)

    return descriptionWrapper
}

async function createCard(i) {    
    divCard.appendChild(createExit())     
    divCard.appendChild(title)
        title.textContent = titles[i].innerText                           
    divCard.appendChild(createInnerDiv(i))          

    divCard.setAttribute('id', i+1)
    cards[i].appendChild(divCard)
}

function toggleOpen(i) {
    createCard((i.path[2].id.substr(5))-1)    
    divCard.addEventListener('click', e => e.stopPropagation())
}
for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    cards[i].addEventListener('click', toggleOpen)
}
```

}